# How to Update a Counter for Fibonacci using Recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

Here's the deal I want to count the recursive calls for a basic Fibonacci code. I already have it so the values will print out in column format but I don't know how to update the recCounter. I think I have to add recCounter++; Somewhere and I don't know where

```
public static int recursionFibonacci(int n) {
    recCounter = 1;
    return fibonacci1(n);
}

public static int fibonacci1(int n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci1(n-1) + fibonacci1(n-2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `recCounter` start off as `0`?

Comment: @arshajii technically it should be -1 (if you decide to count every time you enter fibonacci1)

Comment: @Nirk Why? Setting it to `0` at the start will tell you exactly how many times the function has been called, assuming you increment the count once per call.

Comment: @arshajii depends on what is meant by "recursive".  starting at 0 and incrementing in the function would result in 1 for `n=1` and `n=2`, where technically there are no recursive calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should increment the counter every time you call the function:

```
public static int fibonacci1(int n) {
    recCounter++; // <<-- here
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci1(n-1) + fibonacci1(n-2);
    }
}
```